# Proof with induction even number of letter

Tags: formal-languages

I have to proof that in a word $w$ the number of the letter d is always even.

Let $L \subsetneq \Sigma^*$ be a language over the alphabet $\Sigma = \{a,b,c,d\}$
such that a word $w$ is in $L$ if and only if it is $a$ or $b$ or of the form $w = ducvd$  where $u$ and $v$ are word of $L$.

Examples:

$dacad$, $ddacbdcad$, $dddbcbdcdbcbddcad$

I know there are three cases:

1. $|w| = 0$ the number of the letter d is zero and even
2. $|w| = 1$ and $w = a$ or $w = b$ same as number 1
3. $|w| = 5$ and $w = ducvd$ the number of letter d is even

   I know how induction works, but I don't know to write the base, hypothesis and
   step. I think it works with the length of $w$. Does somebody have a hint?

Comment: The base cases are 1) and 2); the hypothesis is "the number of `d`s in the string is even"; the step is in 3), where you prove the hypothesis by induction over the subwords of $w$, not the length.

Comment: ok but how can I write the induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is by induction on the length of $w$. If $|w| \leq 2$ then necessarily $w = a$ or $w = b$, and in both cases $w$ doesn't contain any $d$'s. If $|w| \geq 3$ then necessarily $w$ is of the form $ducvd$, where $u,v \in L$ are shorter words. By induction, each of $u,v$ contains an even number of $d$'s. It follows that $w$ also contains an even number of $d$'s: if $u,v$ contain $2s,2t$ many $d$'s (respectively), then $w$ contains $2s+2t+2=2(s+t+1)$, which is also even.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively show for every k: There is no w containing 2k+1 d’s.